# Intl package makes mistakes with converting 12:00 PM/ 12:00 AM into 24 hours

Tags: flutter, dart, date, intl

I'm trying to covert dates like 09:00 AM into 24 hours it works perfect with the intl package but I'm getting only one issue that the date 12:00 PM it convert it to 00:00 and 12:00 AM it convert it to 12:00 otherwise all other dates works perfect.

```
 print(DateFormat.Hm()
          .format(DateFormat("HH:mm a").parse('12:00 PM'))); // doesn't work => it prints 00:00

 print(DateFormat.Hm()
          .format(DateFormat("HH:mm a").parse('12:00 AM'))); // doesn't work it prints 12:00

print(DateFormat.Hm()
          .format(DateFormat("HH:mm a").parse('09:00 PM')));// works => 21:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `h` instead of `H`

h        hour in am/pm (1~12)   (Number)           12

H        hour in day (0~23)     (Number)           0

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

```
print(DateFormat.Hm()
          .format(DateFormat("hh:mm a").parse('12:00 PM')));

print(DateFormat.Hm()
          .format(DateFormat("hh:mm a").parse('12:00 AM'))); 

print(DateFormat.Hm()
          .format(DateFormat("hh:mm a").parse('09:00 PM')));
```

Comment: oh thanks I'll try it so like this  DateFormat("hh:mm a") ?

Comment: yes try this format